# Android: Setup and manage VPNs programmatically

Tags: android, android-service, android-internet, android-settings

I would like to setup a VPN configuration and connect to it programmatically.

Similar to what we can do manually at: Settings > Network connections > More networks > VPN

I saw the VpnService class but I don't think it does what I want?

Any idea if we can do that programmatically?